# How to set up Erlang + Emacs with erlang.el?

Tags: windows, emacs, erlang, elisp, devtools

I have downloaded and installed Erlang and [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/cgi-bin/emacsw32-dl-latest.pl). But how do I use `erlang.el` in Emacs? Where do I place it or install it?

I have read [Erlang/OTP R13B04 documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/) and [Erlang mode for Emacs documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.el.html) but I haven't found any information about how to set up it.

**UPDATE 1:** I have found more documentation on [The Erlang mode for Emacs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html). I have typed in the script in my `.emacs`, but I get `File error: Cannot open load file, erlang-start` when I start Emacs, so something is wrong.

**UPDATE 2:** This is how my `.emacs` look like. It's taken directly from the link above.

```
(setq load-path (cons "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.1/lib/tools-2.6.4/emacs"
load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.1")
(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.1/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
```

**UPDATE 3:** I have now tried on another computer, Windows 7, GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1
The `.emacs` file is located at `C:\Users\Jonas\.emacs.d\.emacs` with this content:

```
(setq load-path (cons "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.5/lib/tools-2.6.5.1/emacs" 
load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.5")
(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.5/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
```

When I try to type `M-x erlang-version` in Emacs, I get this message: `[No match]`

Comment: Could you post here the exact content of the relevant part of your .emacs?

Comment: @Roberto: I have posted it in my question now.

Comment: Where is your .emacs file? Do other things in it work?

Comment: Have you tried using an escaped backslash (`\\`) instead of a forward slash in your paths? You could also try using a lower case c for the drive letter...

Comment: @rvirding: I updated the path and content on my Update 3, now on another computer.

Comment: @Adam: Ok, I tried that, but nothing happened.

Comment: @rvirding: I have nothing else in my `.emacs` and I don't know how to create a `.emacs` "Hello world", so I can see that it is loaded. Any link recommendations for this?

Comment: One way to see if your `.emacs` is used is to temporarily move your version, go into Emacs and change some setting (default font for example) and then press `Save Options` in the `Options` menu. This will create a `.emacs` file for you.

Maybe it will be in the same location, or Emacs might decide to put it somewhere else. The setting should be reloaded at restart.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks, that gave me a different path `c:\Users\Jonas\.emacs.d\.emacs` I added my "erlang"-stuff to the file. Now the `M-x erlang-` commands recognized, but when I run them, I get `Cannot open load file: erlang-skels` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see if your `.emacs` is used is to temporarily move your version, go into Emacs and change some setting (default font for example) and then press *Save Options* in the *Options* menu. This will create a `.emacs` file for you.

Maybe it will be in the same location, or Emacs might decide to put it somewhere else. **Find out where it is and add your settings there. The setting should be reloaded at restart.**

If you get the error that `erlang-skels.el` is missing (as it actually is in some R13B releases), I would suggest installing [erlware-mode](http://github.com/erlware/erlware-mode) instead ([download zip here](http://github.com/erlware/erlware-mode/zipball/master)). Put it in your `.emacs.d` folder and change the load-path addition you made to point into that directory instead. It is a much more complete and bug fixed mode with better indentation among other things.

Your config with erlware-mode should look like this (if you put the erlware-mode files inside a `erlware-mode` folder in `.emacs.d`):

```
(setq load-path (cons "C:/Users/Jonas/.emacs.d/.emacs/erlware-mode" 
 load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.5")
(setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.5/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
```

Comment: (a bit late, I know...) - I just set the HOME environment variable to %USERPROFILE% (windows 7) - emacs looks for this variable and creates a .emacs.d folder in your C:\Users\<you>\ folder which is easy to find

Answer (score 5):

You could look to [my article about Emacs & Erlang](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsErlang.html) for details.  Standard way is to put erlang.el somewhere, and load it explicitly with load command.
From my point of view it's better to use erlware-mode, as it contains some extensions over standard erlang-mode.  You can see my erlang config [here](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-erlang.el).  It works under windows, but you need to check which value have env variable %HOME% - the '~' sign is expanded into it value.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried a similar script and got an error. I have updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You can ask me directly, over jabber if you'll have more questions

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure there is a file `erlang-start.el` in `C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.7.1/lib/tools-2.6.4/emacs`? Maybe you should change the `tools-2.6.4` to other name， find out what is the name in your erlang path.